# install ubuntu 20.10 wine 6.0 Paltalk.exe

Tags: wine

Update I have tried the suggestions in the answer but disagree with the answer. Picture attached to show PulseAudio and cam get reconized but cam does not show.

Ubuntu Studio 20.10 (I have tried a many versions but like this one)
wine 6.0 stable (I have tried many version but use this one)
winetricks and lutris are both great tools.

What works
Paltalk works for Audio including PulseAudio
Sound in rooms work
Using the mic in room works
Viewing cams works

What does not work is webcam display
Paltalk reconizes the cam if cam is open in cheese or vlc
Paltalk freezes and crashs if cam is not open in cheeze or vlc

error and issue for cam to work is:

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
Initial process has exited (return code: 9)
```

Run Paltalk Open Cheeze App so cam is running App Preferences terminal output:

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
warn:  winevulkan detected, disabling exclusive fullscreen support
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  911x622
info:    Image count:  3
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
warn:  DXGI: MakeWindowAssociation: Ignoring flags
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  9d8e1289-d7b3-465f-8126-250e349af85d
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  911x622
info:    Image count:  4
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
```

Video & Audio with cheeze still open terminal output

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
err:   D3D11DXGIResource::GetSharedHandle: Stub
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  9d8e1289-d7b3-465f-8126-250e349af85d
warn:  winevulkan detected, disabling exclusive fullscreen support
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  1x1
info:    Image count:  3
info:    Exclusive FS: 2
warn:  DXGI: MakeWindowAssociation: Ignoring flags
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  9d8e1289-d7b3-465f-8126-250e349af85d
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
warn:  D3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface: Unknown interface query
warn:  f8fb5c27-c6b3-4f75-a4c8-439af2ef564c
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Video & Audio With Cheeze clossed Paltalk crashes when opening app Preferences terminal output

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
Initial process has exited (return code: 9)
Monitored process exited.
All monitored processes have exited.
Exit with returncode 9
2021-03-12 13:05:00,948: Game still running (state: running)
2021-03-12 13:05:00,948: Stopping Paltalk Version 1 (wine)
2021-03-12 13:05:03,414: Shutting down Lutris
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install exe files on Linux without Wine. I suggest using this:

https://linuxconfig.org/install-lutris-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Then you can, most likely, install paltalk.exe using Lutris, which is really the easy way.

If you do not want to use Lutris, here is a guide that may help you install figure out how to install Paltalk on Focal Fossa I found it on YouTube. It may help more for your needs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhJu915ztJo

**Update:**
According to the video, Paltalk does not work with Pulseaudio, which is probably what you are using for audio (it is default for Ubuntu). Try using Alsa. Also, this thread on another website may also help. https://www.imfiles.com/topic/best-way-to-run-paltalk-on-linux/

Comment: Does the studio work on focal-fossa also? I have never heard of Lutris but will look it up now. And does the sound work to play in room and hear in rooms along with the cam? As It took me weeks to get sound working correctly trying many ubuntu versions and wine versions.

Comment: It should work on Focal Fossa.

Comment: I think Lutris just uses your system settings for sound, except it also uses Wine to be able to run .exe files.

Comment: I will do some more research

Comment: Paltalk actually does work with PulseAudio and It actually works with my external VoiceLive3 hardware. and I can actually get pal working on a few sound device setups. That video actually just has room sound but can not get mic to work. I have all that solved. room chat was a hard issue to solve but got that fix too. and Pal does reconize my cam it just not display it. to be honest got paltalk working so well it works better that it does on windows or my android phone. The sound with Ubuntu Studio is wow.

Comment: oh the site link also is from 2014 and paltalk stoped ussing paltalk express 2 years ago.

Comment: Oof that is kind of amusing to be honest.

Comment: this is the error now sigh and paltalk not load. i know nothing of vulkan but i learning that is the issue to fix. fixme:vulkan:X11DRV_vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR Application requires child window rendering, which is not implemented yet!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dxvk::DxvkError